Momentum space representaion of an electron-phonon coubling Hamiltonian
I am facing a problem transforming the following Hamiltonian into momentum space:
\begin{align}\hat{H} = -\gamma \sum_\alpha\sum_{i=1}^2  \hat{X}_{i,\alpha} \hat{c}_{i,\alpha}^+\hat{c}_{i,\alpha} +t\sum_i\left(\hat{c}_{i,a}^+\hat{c}_{i+1,b}+ \hat{c}_{i+1,b}^+\hat{c}_{i,a}\right),\end{align}
where i denotes a site and $\alpha$ denotes an orbital.
I will list my steps so far:
1- preform a canonical transformation of the coordinates:
\begin{align}\hat{q}_\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{X}_{1,\alpha}- \hat{X}_{2,\alpha})\quad\text{&}\quad\hat{Q}_\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{X}_{1,\alpha}+ \hat{X}_{2,\alpha})\end{align}
\begin{align}\hat{H} = \sum_\alpha -\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{2}}  \hat{q}_\alpha \left(\hat{c}_{1,\alpha}^+\hat{c}_{1,\alpha}-\hat{c}_{2,\alpha}^+\hat{c}_{2,\alpha}\right) +\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{2}}  \hat{Q}_\alpha \left(\hat{c}_{1,\alpha}^+\hat{c}_{1,\alpha}+\hat{c}_{2,\alpha}^+\hat{c}_{2,\alpha}\right)+t\sum_i\left(\hat{c}_{i,a}^+\hat{c}_{i+1,b}+ \hat{c}_{i+1,b}^+\hat{c}_{i,a}\right) .\end{align}
2- Insert the momentum representation of the creation and annihilation operators:
\begin{align} \hat{c}_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k e^{ikx}\hat{c}_k\quad\text{&}\quad \hat{c}_x^+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k e^{-ikx}\hat{c}_k^+,
\end{align}
Note that N=2 and k are either 0 or $\pi$
My problem is that I get a matrix that mixes k components:
\begin{align}
\hat{H} = \sum_k \begin{pmatrix}c_{k,a}^+&c_{k,b}^+\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{2}}  \hat{Q}_a&te^{ik}\\te^{-ik}&\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{2}}\hat{Q}_b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_{k,a}\\ c_{k,b}\end{pmatrix} +
\sum_{k^\prime\neq k} \begin{pmatrix}c_{k,a}^+&c_{k,b}^+\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{2}}  \hat{q}_a&0\\0&\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{2}}\hat{q}_b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_{k^\prime,a}\\ c_{k^\prime,b}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
This is a 4x4 matrix, right?
I am stuck at this stage because , I don't know how to make this a block diagonal form or get rid of the k mixing part. I thought this Hamiltonian is translation invariant (with periodic boundary conditions) which allows me to use the momentum representation to make it a block diagonal form.
Any help? As I have been scratching my head at this problem long enough :'(

IMHO, you have confused the site and the orbital indices for the phonon variables...

Do you mean I should write $\hat{X}{\alpha,i}$ instead of $\hat{X}{i,\alpha}$

For c-operators it seems that $i$ is the cite index (running from $-\infty$ to $+\igty$), whereas $\alpha=a,b$, but for $X$ operators this is manifestly not the case - even in Hamiltonian ($\sum_{i=1}^2$ is either a mistake... or the Hamiltonian is manifestly not translationally invariant, but coupled only for sites $1,2$.)

I see what you mean. There are only two sites in the system, but would that stop it from being translation invariant? Shifting the i index in $H$ and using $i+2\equiv i$ shows that $H$ is translation invariant, right?

In this case it is not even obvious that your final Hamiltonian really breaks the transnational in-variance. At least your phonon transformation seems to be specific to this two-site case (which allows you to omit phonon momentum from explicit consideration). I suggest doing it for an arbitrary number of sites, and then looking specifically at the case of two sites, if this is really what interests you.
